# How to correct model "summaries" in REST?

Tags: rest, microservices

A microservice exposes a canonical REST API to deal with two resources: `teams` and `matches`, where a match is played by two teams and have a score.

1. `post /team` will add a new team
2. `get /teams` will get all the teams
3. `get /team/{id}` will return a specific team

The same canonical implementation is provided for the `match` resource. Now, there are two clients applications of this microservice:

- A public website which needs to display for each team the total number of matches, the total number of wins and total losses
- A private website which needs to display the greatest loss and the player who received most red cards

Let's add the following constraints:

1. We don't want to return this summary information in the `team` resource because it might be computationally expensive
2. The two summaries have different permissioning: according to the header in the HTTP request we might accept / reject the request

What would be an appropriate way to design an API for this use case?

- A single endpoint with a query parameter, which doesn't lead to explosion in the number of endpoints but return responses which are very different one from each other
- Multiple endpoints (internal-summary, external-summary, scores-summary, faults-summary)

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, in canonical rest REST API design path parameters and query parameters are used for different purposes:

> path: identify specific resource/resources,
>   query: sort/filter
>   resources.

In your use case we have to deal with summarized data, which can be seen as a different resource, since in general it contains data of a different nature than the one in your /teams and /matches paths.

In my opinion a good design for this use case may be doing a **/stats path** and then **filter it by a query parameter** (matches,wins,faults,...), this helps clarity and doesn't convolute the api too much, in the future you can also easily add more stats resources in an easy and maintanable way.

Comment: Using the filter by query parameter would still change the shape, unless you would return an array of stats with two fields: stat name and stat value